# jQuery doesn't seem to work when previewing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to coding so I need help from you guys! 
I wrote these codes to run a test but I can't seem to get the jQuery to load when previewing in Chrome. (I use Atom to code)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p>This is just a test</p>

    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
  color: #6D9CAE;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

h2 {
  color: #bb2025;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

p {
  color: #54748B;
  font-family: Avenir;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  background-color: #223C4A;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.active {
  background-color: #a5b000;
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').hover(function(){
    $('div').addClass('.active')
  });
});
```

I'm trying to get the div to change a color when hover over but it just can't work. Not sure if I did anything wrong with the javascript. 
I tried to copy a working code (html, css, script) from somewhere and preview it using chrome and safari and that won't work either.

So, how do I get the script to work when previewing??

Thanks!!

Comment: addClass and removeClass take the name of the class not the css selector, so it would be `addClass("active")`

Comment: "previewing" means what? You mean when you open the page in browser?

Comment: Note that although implementing this sort of feature is good practice for somebody learning jquery, changing the colour (or other styles) on hover is something easily done just with CSS, no need for any JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the '.' from '.active' when you use '.addClass'

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').hover(function(){
    $('div').addClass('active');
  });
});
```